# ng-repeat track by with hashKey default

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-track-by

Question:

Is it possible to define an ng-repeat track by expression which will use a particular attribute if it exists, but use the default $$hashKey behavior if that attribute is undefined?

Context:

I have a chat application which displays an array of JSON "post" objects which have id's. Typically, I would do

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts track by post.id">{{post.content}}</div>
```

However, since I want the app to feel responsive to the user, when a user adds a new chat, I immediately push it onto the array BEFORE I make the create API call. I then update the id if the API response was successful, or update a "failed" field if the API response was not successful.

This means it is possible for the `posts` array to have multiple post objects which have value `undefined` for id if there were failed posts.

So I'm hoping it's possible to still use $$hashKey when there is no id defined.

Comment: Not sure about the use of `$$haskey`, but what about giving it a temporary ID? Take last ID +1 or something. Although, I suppose this could give issues if you have a lot of users.

Comment: Generate one with a random number.

Comment: what does `track by post.id` give you that `track by $index` wouldn't in this case? the only thing that `track by` does is ensure that angular can identify a unique row, and `$index` is definitely a unique identifier....

Comment: @EnigmaRM: last ID + 1 won't work cause that could conflict with a later post (e.g. if that post fails)

Comment: @HankScorpio: hrm... is this suggested? Could this still cause conflicts? or is the probability low enough that it would never matter?

Comment: @Claies: There are times when I want to replace a post and not re-render the DOM. I do admit that it isn't that common in this case, but I'm also interested in this question for an application with todo lists (e.g. a list of tasks), which has the same problem. For that case, it would be common to have to replace a task due to new information from the server.

Comment: what does that mean, "replace a post and not re-render the DOM"? and how would `track by post.id` make that work when `track by $index` wouldn't? I'm still not clear on what it is you think the difference would be.

Comment: @Claies: Suppose I were to get a post from the server with updated properties. I want to be able to replace it in the array without re-rendering the DOM. My impression is that by doing `track by post.id`, angular can map the new object to the original DOM. If I were to use $index, I would have to find the position of the post and replace it in the array, right? Would that work if I have an orderBy?

Comment: no, that isn't how `track by` works.  you would still need to find the item in the array, no matter how you are tracking it in the DOM.

Comment: @Claies: but would track by $index work with orderBy? it seems like the $index could change in that case.

Comment: it wouldn't work with your theoretical code anyway, since you are suggesting that these objects have an `id` that you want to use but don't know what it is yet;  when you *do* know what the `id` is, it's just going to mess with the sorting anyway.

Comment: either way, this really feels like an XY problem; you are asking about how to work with some vague mechanic that you think will solve the problem of inserting a fake object, instead of actually asking about ways to handle fake objects.